# Detect software used to open an XLSX file with Macro or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I search a way to know if an XLSX file is currently opened in Excel, libreoffice-calc or another sheet software.

The goal is to display a warning in a cell only if the file is NOT open with excel.

Is there an official Macro that would allow that? Or maybe a trick with a macro existing in excel  and not libreoffice?

Or as a last resort, a solution to detect this information in VBA script?

Thanks!

---

Comment: If you really mean xlsx then that doesn't hold any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Excel the following

```
Application.Name
```

will return `Microsoft Excel`, and

```
Application.Version
```

will return the Excel version like `16.0`.

You can write a warning into a cell like *"Please open edit this file only with Excel"* and remove it with an Excel VBA code. Note that the warning will then be also there if Macros are disabled.